# SQL Correlation and/or alias

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I teach web design in high school and I am coming up with a new activity for my students. I have 2 tables, see image below, and I am trying to output the sentence that follows the image. Here is the code that I have so far...

```
select sealTime.id,
       sealTime.student,
       sealTime.reqTeacher,
       sealTime.asignTeacher,
       sahsUsers.status,
       sahsUsers.title,
       sahsusers.firstname,
       sahsusers.lastname
from sealTime
INNER JOIN sahsUsers ON sealTime.studentId = sahsUsers.id
WHERE sealTime.id = '345'
```

[image: table layout]

The current code only outputs the student first and last name,

```
<cfoutput query="names"> 
     <p>#firstname# #lastname# has been asked by #title# #lastname# 
     to be excused to #title# #lastname#'s room today during flex period.    
</cfoutput>
```

This is what I am getting as a output

> David Johnson has been asked by 36 to be excused to 35 room today
>   during flex period.

Comment: What exact output you required for ID = 345?

Comment: I am just using it as an example, I am trying to output the sentence that is written at the bottom of the image.

Comment: Not related to the question, but in the realm of best practices A) You don't need quotes around INTEGER values, i.e. `WHERE sealTime.id = 345`. B) If "345" is a some sort of client supplied value, like a URL parameter, always use cfqueryparam to prevent sql injection i.e. `WHERE sealTime.id = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.someParamName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this, if I wasn't thinking too hard about it, I'd probably just loop over sealTime and within that loop, do selects from sahsUsers for each of the names.  If the rules stated that it had to be a single SQL statement, or the loop and select method was too slow because of the sheer volume of data, I might do something like:

```
SELECT sealTime.id,
       sealTime.student,
       sealTime.reqTeacher,
       sealTime.asignTeacher,
       student.status studentStatus,
       student.title studentTitle,
       student.firstname studentFirstname,
       student.lastname studentLastname,
       teacher1.status teacher1Status,
       teacher1.title teacher1Title,
       teacher1.firstname teacher1Firstname,
       teacher1.lastname teacher1Lastname,
       teacher2.status teacher2Status,
       teacher2.title teacher2Title,
       teacher2.firstname teacher2Firstname,
       teacher2.lastname teacher2Lastname
FROM sealTime
INNER JOIN sahsUsers student ON sealTime.studentId = student.id
INNER JOIN sahsUsers teacher1 ON sealTime.reqTeacher = teacher1.id
INNER JOIN sahsUsers teacher2 ON sealTime.asignTeacher = teacher2.id
WHERE sealTime.id = '345'
```

Then assuming you named your query "query", and assuming teacher1 (reqTeacher) is the one doing the requesting (if not, just swap teacher1 and teacher2), you can just do:

```
#query.studentFirstname# #query.studentLastname# has been asked by #query.teacher1Title# #query.teacher1Lastname# to be excused to #query.teacher2Title# #query.teacher2Lastnaame#'s room today during flex period.
```

This is also assuming you've got checks in place to make sure that the IDs in the reqTeacher and asignTeacher columns in the sealTime table are ALWAYS either teachers or admins, and never students, and that the IDs in the student column are always students, never admins or teachers.  You could build checks for that in and error if it's not right, though that would be easier with the loop and query method than the single-sql-query method.

Comment: Sorry, just realized talk of looping is probably jumping ahead, since you're specifying a sealTime ID in the query. What I meant by the "loop and select" method, if you're just looking at one sealTime ID, would be three different queries, all of which are just like what you already have, except name one "student", one "teacher1" and one "teacher2", and change sealTime.studentID to sealtime reqTeacher in teacher1, and sealTime.asignTeacher in teacher2; then you can use student.firstname, student.lastname, teacher1.title, teacher1.lastname, teacher2.title and teacher2.lastname in the cfoutput.

Comment: -1 Don't use looping. It's an extremely inefficient way of retrieving data. SQL is a set based language. It's specifically designed for manipulating groups of data with JOIN's, not procedural loops. So stick with JOIN's.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help, this solved my problem. What is it called when you came up with teacher1?

Comment: If an answer suggests looping over a query and then doing a query during each iteration of that loop...there is most certainly a better way.

Comment: The answer could be greatly improved by eliminating looping references and sticking with the JOIN. (Editing answers to improve them is encouraged on S.O.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

```
select sahsusers.firstname + ' ' + 
   sahsusers.lastname +
   ' has been asked by ' +
   Cast(sealTime.reqTeacher as varchar) +
   ' to be excused to '+
   Cast(sealTime.asignTeacher as varchar) +
   ' room today during flex period.'

From sealTime
INNER JOIN sahsUsers  ON sealTime.studentId = sahsUsers.id
WHERE sealTime.id = '345'
```

Comment: Here is the cfoutput code I am trying to use:`<cfoutput query="names">
  
<p>#firstname# #lastname# has been asked by #title# #lastname# to be excused to #title# #lastname#'s room today during flex period.
 
</cfoutput>`